# ball 2d animation

Tags: 2d, physics, animation, javascript, html-canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [canvas ball physics animation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29412/canvas-ball-physics-animation)

I want to animate ball in html canvas like this.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(75, 75, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJWuw.jpg

start position is left top corner and ball's maximum height position is always the same

also I don't want to use javascript physics libraries

thanks